# Cannot understand 802.11 Data Frame format in PcapNG file

Tags: python, wireshark, wifi, pcap-ng

I have *PcapNG* files created by Wireshark, which I try to parse with `python-pcapng`.

However, I cannot figure out how to reconcile the output I receive from `FileScanner`'s `packet_payload_info` with the *802.11 Data frame format*: [image: 802.11 Data frame format]

This is the output I get (my code is at the bottom):

```
magic_number 0xa0d0d0a
SectionHeader(version_major=1, version_minor=0, section_length=-1, options=Options({'shb_userappl': [u'Dumpcap 1.12.4 (v1.12.4-0-gb4861da from master-1.12)'], 'shb_os': [u'Mac OS X 10.10.2, build 14C109 (Darwin 14.1.0)']}))

magic_number 0x1
InterfaceDescription(link_type=127, reserved='\x00\x00', snaplen=262144, options=Options({'if_os': [u'Mac OS X 10.10.2, build 14C109 (Darwin 14.1.0)'], 'if_tsresol': [6], 'if_name': [u'en1']}))

magic_number 0x6
EnhancedPacket(interface_id=0, timestamp_high=332139, timestamp_low=2801116064L, packet_payload_info=(45, 45, '\x00\x00\x19\x00o\x08\x00\x00`I\xb2&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x18q\x16@\x01\xb1\xaa\x00\xb4\x00\x90\x00\xf4\x0f\x1b\xb8sL`\x92\x175\x00\x01\xe3\xcf\x00\x12'), options=Options({}))

packet_payload_info      : (45, 45, '\x00\x00\x19\x00o\x08\x00\x00`I\xb2&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x18q\x16@\x01\xb1\xaa\x00\xb4\x00\x90\x00\xf4\x0f\x1b\xb8sL`\x92\x175\x00\x01\xe3\xcf\x00\x12') 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 60 49 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 18 71 16 40 01 B1 AA 00 B4 00 90 00 F4 0F 1B B8 73 4C 60 92 17 35 00 01 E3 CF 00 12 

packet_payload_data (bin): 00000000 00000000 00011001 00000000 01101111 00001000 00000000 00000000 01100000 01001001 10110010 00100110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010010 00011000 01110001 00010110 01000000 00000001 10110001 10101010 00000000 10110100 00000000 10010000 00000000 11110100 00001111 00011011 10111000 01110011 01001100 01100000 10010010 00010111 00110101 00000000 00000001 11100011 11001111 00000000 00010010
```

### Could you tell me where does the `packet_payload_data` fit in the 802.11 Data frame?*

- i.e., where does its first byte fit in the frame

***Python code:***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pcapng import FileScanner

def hex_str_to_num(hex_str,out_format='X'):
    if out_format.upper() == 'B':
        return ' '.join(format(ord(x), out_format).zfill(8) for x in hex_str)
    else:
        return ' '.join(format(ord(x), out_format).zfill(2) for x in hex_str)


PCAPNG = "/cygdrive/c/tmp/trace3.pcapng"
MAX = 3
ENHANCEDPACKET_ID = 6

with open(PCAPNG, "r") as pcapng_file:
    scanner = FileScanner(pcapng_file)
    counter = MAX
    for block in scanner:
        print
        print "magic_number",hex(block.magic_number)
        print block

        if block.magic_number == ENHANCEDPACKET_ID:
            print
            payload_data = block.packet_payload_info[2]
            print "packet_payload_info      :",block.packet_payload_info,"\n"
            print "packet_payload_data (hex):",hex_str_to_num(payload_data,"X"),"\n"
            print "packet_payload_data (bin):",hex_str_to_num(payload_data,"b")

        counter -= 1
        if not counter:
            break
```

### EDIT 1:

If I print several `EnhancedPacket`'s `packet_payload_data`, I notice that all of them start with `00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00`. Now, the `08` is the data frame marker, which make me suspect that the `packet_payload_data` isn't just the payload data, but also includes the *Frame control* bits.

```
packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 60 49 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 18 71 16 40 01 B1 AA 00 B4 00 90 00 F4 0F 1B B8 73 4C 60 92 17 35 00 01 E3 CF 00 12 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 92 49 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 18 71 16 40 01 CD AA 00 C4 00 60 00 60 92 17 35 00 01 F7 65 6E 79 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 09 4A B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 18 71 16 40 01 CA AA 00 94 00 00 00 60 92 17 35 00 01 F4 0F 1B B8 73 4C 04 00 C0 23 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 58 D0 59 5C 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 5F 51 B2 26 00 00 00 00 52 6C 71 16 40 01 B2 AA 00 B4 00 1C 1B F4 0F 1B B8 73 4C 60 92 17 35 00 01 33 20 02 04 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 86 51 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 6C 71 16 40 01 CA AA 00 C4 00 4C 00 60 92 17 35 00 01 EE 12 B7 D7 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 EE 53 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 6C 71 16 40 01 B1 AA 00 B4 00 74 00 F4 0F 1B B8 73 4C 60 92 17 35 00 01 33 20 02 04 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 15 54 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 6C 71 16 40 01 CB AA 00 C4 00 4C 00 60 92 17 35 00 01 EE 12 B7 D7 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 98 56 B2 26 00 00 00 00 52 6C 71 16 40 01 B2 AA 00 AB 00 74 00 F4 0F 1B B8 73 3C E4 44 DF 67 09 14 3A 0A 24 04 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 C0 56 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 6C 71 16 40 01 CB AA 00 C4 00 4C 00 60 92 17 35 00 01 EE 12 B7 D7 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 E8 58 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 18 71 16 40 01 B1 AA 00 B4 00 90 00 F4 0F 1B B8 73 4C 60 92 17 35 00 01 E3 CF 00 12 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 1B 59 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 18 71 16 40 01 CD AA 00 C4 00 60 00 60 92 17 35 00 01 F7 65 6E 79 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 92 59 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 18 71 16 40 01 CA AA 00 94 00 00 00 60 92 17 35 00 01 F4 0F 1B B8 73 4C 04 00 D0 23 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF B0 51 F7 7B 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 A0 69 B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 6C 71 16 40 01 C6 AA 00 B4 00 C0 00 50 2E 5C DA 81 9D F4 0F 1B B8 73 4C B4 E2 C5 B7 

packet_payload_data (hex): 00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00 17 6A B2 26 00 00 00 00 12 6C 71 16 40 01 C5 AA 00 B4 00 C0 00 50 2E 5C DA 81 9D F4 0F 1B B8 73 4C B4 E2 C5 B7
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to download your PCAP file for further investigations ?

Comment: As requested, @Sylvain - here's a URL to a directory containing both a PcapNG file and my Python script: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bw5McUt95YdefnZUaGFDTUQ3TVVWLWtIZjBONTlRdFJnOEpwTzBTSEM5T19RYmdJcm1kS0U&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do *not* assume that, just because you captured on an 802.11 interface, the frame data begins with an 802.11 header.  It might begin with a "radio metadata" header, for example, with the 802.11 header following it.

*ALL* programs that read pcap-ng files must:

- read all the Interface Description Blocks, and remember, at minimum, the ordinal number of that IDB (which will be used later as the interface ID) and the LinkType value for the interface;
- when processing a packet block, look up the LinkType value for the interface with the specified interface ID, and use that to interpret the raw packet data.

[The official list of LinkType values](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) indicates what the values are and how the packet data should be interpreted for that value.  Never ever ever ever ever ever ever assume what the packet data will look like; always check the LinkType value.

(This applies to pcap files as well; always check the file's link-layer header type.)

Now, note that `00 00 19 00 6F 08 00 00` could possibly be the beginning of a [radiotap](http://www.radiotap.org) header, with a version value of 0, pad byte of 0, and little-endian length of 25 bytes, with the first presence-bit word being 0x0000086F.  That presence-bit word would say that the fields that are present would be [TSFT](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/TSFT) (8 bytes), [Flags](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Flags) (1 byte), [Rate](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Rate) (1 byte), [Channel](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Channel) (4 bytes), [Antenna signal](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Antenna%20signal) (1 byte), [Antenna noise](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Antenna%20noise) (1 byte), and [Antenna](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Antenna) (1 byte).  The version, pad byte, length, and presence bit word are 8 bytes, for a total of 8+8+1+1+4+1+1+1 = 25 bytes.

So I would most definitely *NOT* assume that you're looking at an 802.11 header!  You must check the LinkType; if it's 127 (LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_RADIOTAP), the packets begin with a radiotap header, followed by an 802.11 header.  If it's 105 (LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11), they begin with an 802.11 header.

The 802.11 header, whether it follows the radiotap (or other radio metadata) header or is at the beginning of the raw packet data, is a raw 802.11 header, so it begins with a Frame Control field, followed by Duration, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @Guy. If we look at my OP - we see:
magic_number 0x1
InterfaceDescription(link_type=127, ...
So, just to make sure I understand you: FileScanner's packet_payload_info start with the radiotap header, followed by an 802.11 header?

Comment: If the Interface Description Block for the interface on which the packet in question was received (do *NOT* assume that the file has only one Interface Description Block!) has a link_type of 127, that's LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_RADIOTAP, and the payload information will start with a radiotap header, followed by an 802.11 header.  (Note that if the "frame has padding between 802.11 header and payload (to 32-bit boundary)" bit is set in the [Flags](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Flags) field, there may be padding between the 802.11 header and payload.)

Comment: A very instructive answer Guy ! @user1656850 Loading the pcap file into wireshark will convince you that you have a _Radiotab Header v0_ at the start of your frames. Then, the _IEEE802.11 header_ starts at offset 19h of the captured frame